# Hausdorff convergence in bounded set preserves the volume

Tags: real-analysis, counterexamples

I was wondering if Hausdorff convergence relates to the volume of the converging sets. In particular, let $(C_n)$ be a sequence of closed sets contained in a bounded, closed set $Q$. Assume that $|C_n|=m$ and $C_n\to C$ in the Hausdorff sense, with $C$ being a closed set in $Q$. Does it hold $|C|=m$?

Obviously, if I considered the sequence in $\mathbb R^N$ it is not true, but I have no clues on a counterexample in the bounded case.

Answer (score 2):

This is not so. Let $Q = [0,1]$ and $C_n \subset [0,1]$ be dyadic numbers, that is $C_n = \{ k 2^{-n} \mid k = 0,\dots,2^n \}$. Then $C_n \to [0,1]$ with respect to Hausdorff distance, but $\mathcal{H}^1(C_n) = 0$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 0):

For many interesting examples, investigate [space-filling curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve)

[image: pic]

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is (rather strongly) NO.

Let $0 \leq b \leq 1,$ let $\mathcal K$ be the Hausdorff hyperspace of nonempty closed subsets of $[0,1],$ and let ${\mathcal K}_b = \{E \in {\mathcal K}: \; |E| \geq b\}.$ Then it is fairly straightforward to show $\{E \in {\mathcal K}: \; |E| = b\}$ is dense in ${\mathcal K}_b.$

Thus, if $0 \leq b \leq c \leq 1$ and $C$ is **any** closed subset of $[0,1]$ with $|C| = c$ (hence, $C \in {\mathcal K}_b),$ then there exists a sequence $\{C_n\}$ of closed subsets of $[0,1]$ such that for each $n$ we have $|C_n| = b$ and $C_n \rightarrow C$ in the Hausdorff sense. Note that @Leo Moos's example is an instance of this for the case $b=0$ and $c=1.$

In fact, $\{E \in {\mathcal K}: \; |E| = b\}$ is not just dense in ${\mathcal K}_b,$ but $\{E \in {\mathcal K}: \; |E| = b\}$ is actually co-meager in ${\mathcal K}_b.$ $({\mathcal K}_b$ is a closed subspace of the complete metric space ${\mathcal K},$ and thus ${\mathcal K}_b$ is itself a complete metric space.) Thus, almost all elements—in the Baire category sense—in ${\mathcal K}_b$ have the minimum possible measure, namely $b.$

A proof of this and even stronger results can be found in Timothy H. Steele's 1994 Ph.D. dissertation [**Omega Limit Sets for Functions Exhibiting Controlled Growth**](https://www.mathgenealogy.org/id.php?id=17115) (Proposition 3.2). For example, in addition to requiring that each of the co-meagerly many sets has measure equal to $b,$ we can require each of them to be perfect and nowhere dense and to consist of only numbers that do not belong to a countable set given in advance, such as the rationals. This co-meager result is probably in one of Steele's papers, but I wasn't able to find it now.